Order of the group of upper triangular matrices over $\mathbb{Z_p}$
I was learning about Frobenius proof of Sylow's first theorem, and in the proof he uses Cayley's theorem to make a map from the group $G$ to $S_n$ and then uses the permutation matrix to map from $S_n \to GL(n,\mathbb{Z}_p)$. Then he states that $TU(n,\mathbb{Z}_p\})$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z}_p)$.
I was able to find at MSE that for $n = 3$, its possible to prove by induction that $TU(3,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ has order $p$, but I can't find an argument that show that form any $n$, the elements of $TU(n,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ have order $p$.
Can someone provide a proof or a way of  how to reach it? Thanks in advance.

What you're trying to prove isn't true: the elements don't all have order $p$, nor is the subgroup of order $p$. Instead, just count elements: you know what the diagonal is, and what is under the diagonal. How many choices are there for each spot above the diagonal?

Notation: use \mathbb{Z}_p rather than \mathbb{Z_p} so that only the $\mathbb{Z}$ gets typeset in blackboard.

would it be $p^{n \choose 2}$ So any element would have order dividing this number, since it is a cyclic subgroup of $TU(n,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ Is it right?

Yes, once you know it's a subgroup, and the order is is $p^{\binom{n}{2}}$, Lagrange's theorem shows every element has order dividing this.
